# twitter apiを利用して位置情報を取得

Tags: twitter, 地理情報

特定文字が含まれているタイムラインがどの地域で作成されたか確認したいです。
この場合どのtwitter apiを使えば実現可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

ツイートの検索は

- [GET search/tweets | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets)

で行えます。
geo 属性が付いたツイートに限定することも可能で、ジオコード `geocode` を使います。引数は `緯度,経度,距離km` の形式です。

サンプルコードは Ruby で。

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# coding: utf-8

gem 'twitter', '>= 5.0.0' # twitter gem のバージョンが 5 以上を指定
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(
# API のアクセストークンを登録
  consumer_key:        'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY',
  consumer_secret:     'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET',
  access_token:        'ACCESS_TOKEN',
  access_token_secret: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'
)
since_id = nil 

loop do
  tweets = client.search(
    "love",             # 検索キーワードを "love" に
#    geocode: "40.7033121,-73.979681,10km", # around New York
    count: 100,         # 読み込みツイート数（API 上限が100）
    since_id: since_id  # 同じツイートを取得しないようにツイートの読み込み開始 id を指定
  )
  since_id = tweets.first.id if tweets.first
  tweets.take(100).reverse.each do |tw|
    next if tw.geo.lat.nil? # ツイートに緯度が含まれていない場合には次のツイートへ
                            # client.search の引数に geocode を入れる場合には不要
    puts "#{tw.place.name}, #{tw.place.country} (#{tw.geo.lat}, #{tw.geo.long}) @ #{tw.created_at}\n@#{tw.user.screen_name} (@ #{tw.user.location}): #{tw.text}\n---"
    # ツイート検索結果を1ツイート2行にして出力
    # 都市名, 国名 (緯度, 経度) @ ツイート時刻
    # @アカウント名 (@ アカウントの登録地名): ツイート本文 
  end
  sleep 10 #10秒毎に繰り返す
end
```

スクリプトの解説を少しすると、

- `tw` インスタンスに各ツイートの情報が入ります。 API から JSON で返ってきた内容とほぼ同じです。
- `tw.place.name` には JSON の "place" の "name" が、以下同様に `tw.place.country` には "place" の　"country" が、 `tw.geo.lat` には "geo" の "coordinates" の 一つ目（つまり緯度）、 `tw.geo.long` には "geo" の "coordinates" の 二つ目（つまり経度）が、それぞれ返されるようになっています。
- geocode を指定していれば、検索キーワードは空文字でも API 的には OK のようです。（参考：[The Search API | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)）
- Ruby 以外の言語でも JSON を見れば経緯度を取得出来ると思います。

API から返ってきた JSON の例：

```js
{
  "created_at":"Tue Feb 03 14:36:14 +0000 2015",
  "id":562620584031318018,
  "id_str":"562620584031318018",
  "text":"@hztttao____ #GetWellSoonTao 孩子，我们都知道你有多幺的努力工作，但是健康更重要啊！真的心疼你们！Please take care your health carefully boy! Love you all",
  "source":"Twitter for Android","
  truncated":false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id":2483888760,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2483888760",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name":"hztttao____",
  "user":{
    "id":246864766,
    "id_str":"246864766",
    "name":"tsinychong",
    "screen_name":"tsinychong",
    "location":"Tawau, Sabah, East Malaysia",
    "profile_location":null,
    "description":"I am a Malaysian Chinese lady. I was attracted by Suju's & EXO's songs & dancing, that's why i'm here.",
    "url":null,
    "entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},
    "protected":false,
    "followers_count":6,
    "friends_count":72,
    "listed_count":0,
    "created_at":"Thu Feb 03 16:36:39 +0000 2011",
    "favourites_count":7,
    "utc_offset":28800,
    "time_zone":"Kuala Lumpur",
    "geo_enabled":true,
    "verified":false,
    "statuses_count":1261,
    "lang":"en",
    "contributors_enabled":false,
    "is_translator":false,
    "is_translation_enabled":false,
    "profile_background_color":"EBEBEB",
    "profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme7/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme7/bg.gif",
    "profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png",
    "profile_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png",
    "profile_link_color":"990000",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color":"DFDFDF",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"F3F3F3",
    "profile_text_color":"333333",
    "profile_use_background_image":true,
    "default_profile":false,
    "default_profile_image":true,
    "following":false,
    "follow_request_sent":false,
    "notifications":false
  },
  "geo":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.262577,117.9022693]},
  "coordinates":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[117.9022693,4.262577]},
  "place":{
    "id":"eeb42e1fdfb3cfe4",
    "url":"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/eeb42e1fdfb3cfe4.json",
    "place_type":"city",
    "name":"Tawau",
    "full_name":"Tawau, Sabah",
    "country_code":"MY",
    "country":"Malaysia",
    "contained_within":[],
    "bounding_box":{
      "type":"Polygon",
      "coordinates":[[
        [116.9334819,4.1657558],
        [118.3555885,4.1657558],
        [118.3555885,4.7962486],
        [116.9334819,4.7962486]
      ]]
    },
    "attributes":{}
  },
  "contributors":null,
  "retweet_count":0,
  "favorite_count":0,
  "entities":{
    "hashtags":[{"text":"GetWellSoonTao","indices":[13,28]}],
    "symbols":[],
    "user_mentions":[{
      "screen_name":"hztttao____",
      "name":"EXO-TAO黄子韬",
      "id":2483888760,
      "id_str":"2483888760",
      "indices":[0,12]
    }],
    "urls":[]
  },
  "favorited":false,
  "retweeted":false,
  "lang":"zh"
}
```

実行結果例：

```
Tawau, Malaysia (4.262577, 117.9022693) @ 2015-02-03 23:36:14 +0900
@tsinychong (@ Tawau, Sabah, East Malaysia): @hztttao____ #GetWellSoonTao 孩子，我们都知道你有多幺的努力工作，但是健康更重要啊！真的心疼你们！Please take care your health carefully boy! Love you all
---
Ulu Kelang, Malaysia (3.1958138, 101.7770204) @ 2015-02-03 23:36:27 +0900
@ayieshcasanova (@ ): I love you so much - sent to myself
Kau pehal - reply back to myself
Sebab aku sayang diri sendiri la kau masih hidup sampai skrg . K gila
---
Quixeramobim, Brasil (0.0, 0.0) @ 2015-02-03 23:36:27 +0900
@jackinhanj (@ Quixeramobim/ce): A Tuesday with much love that clip ♥ #FourFiveSecondsOnVEVO @rihanna
---
Quilpué, Chile (-33.0484477, -71.4708018) @ 2015-02-03 23:37:03 +0900
@PereiraCote (@ Quilpué-Chile): #HappyBDayJustinTimberlake i love you!!!! :'3 #Mirrors mi cancion favorita de el :)
---
Île-de-France, France (0.0, 0.0) @ 2015-02-03 23:38:11 +0900
@allxflouis (@ France): @Real_Liam_Payne 
Ur story is the most touching i've never heard
I cry when I remember what you went through
U r our warrior. Love ya x1
---
Merkez, Türkiye (0.0, 0.0) @ 2015-02-03 23:38:12 +0900
@gltenmer (@ ): you make me happy @justinbieber ,please.
FOLLOW ME ,PLEASE.
I am TURKISH BELİEBER.
SEE ME ,PLZ.♥
I LOVE U SO MUCH♥♥ 
x3.078
---
Lecce, Italia (0.0, 0.0) @ 2015-02-03 23:40:18 +0900
@Cinzia268 (@ Collepasso): Love me like you do.
---
Liloy, Republika ng Pilipinas (8.1198248, 122.6804241) @ 2015-02-03 23:42:01 +0900
@tonetmurcia (@ Murcia Spain): like what..while watching Unforgettable Love there's a certain question that kept on poking my head..jeez I feel you Nina
---
Shanghai, 中华人民共和国 (31.21431856, 121.55950506) @ 2015-02-03 23:43:54 +0900
@lilannash (@ Shanghai): #pureandwhole spring new dishes: I already love all of them. This is my favourite place after my… http://t.co/jKD9ndRfqW
---
Los Angeles, United States (0.0, 0.0) @ 2015-02-03 23:45:16 +0900
@awarde (@ ): @chankpc @CNM_JLin_Vids i love how the NY media basically said that we know r hands have been tied with the Lakers
---
```

geocode を指定しない場合は
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=love&count=100&since_id=(since_id)`
geocode を指定した場合は
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=love&geocode=40.7033121,-73.979681,10km&count=100&since_id=(since_id)`
と同じになると思います（(since_id) にはツイート id が入ります）。

なお、実行結果例からも分かりますが、経緯度が (0.0, 0.0) になっているツイートが多く見られます。 <del>geocode での検索指定はおそらく経緯度から算出していると思われますので、位置情報に都市が含まれるツイートであっても geocode の条件を含めると検索結果から欠落してしまうおそれがあります。</del>ご注意ください。

若干異なっていました。

> **Geolocalization**: ... When conducting geo searches, the search API will first attempt to find tweets which have lat/long within the queried geocode, and in case of not having success, it will attempt to find tweets created by users whose profile location can be reverse geocoded into a lat/long within the queried geocode, meaning that is possible to receive tweets which do not include lat/long information.
>   [The Search API | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

geocode での検索では Profile の位置情報も使うようです。

Answer (score 0):

動作確認はしていないので間違っているかもしれませんが、
[`users/search`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search) で検索し、ツイートの`geo`属性を確認するといいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
geo属性がない人がほとんどですが、geo属性がなければ検索しない条件などを入れることも可能ですか？

Comment: そのようなAPIもありそうなので少し探してみましたが見つかりませんでした。他の詳しい方に回答をお任せすることにします。